# Can I apply for residency permit in Finland on a Schengen Visa?

Tags: resident-permit, schengen, pakistani-citizen, finland

Actually I'm a startup founder from **Pakistan** and my team will be joining an accelerator program in Finland this Fall, which is hardly 1.5 months.

Now the problem is that there is **NO** Finnish Embassy in Pakistan and consular matters are handled by the Dutch (Netherlands) Embassy, but it **ONLY** handles Schengen Visa (Short Term 90 Days) while we'll be staying for almost 4 months and possibly longer.

My research and Dutch embassy says that we'll have to apply for a residence permit from Finnish embassies in either the UAE, India, China, Nepal etc. all of which require us to apply for visas also (no visa free entry). Even if we manage to apply and get a visa in lets says a week or so, then still the residency permit application takes at least **3 MONTHS** to process! By then our accelerator program will be past midway.

My research also said that one can apply for Residency in Finland itself in exceptional cases. Also that Residency Application in Finland are handled by Federal Immigration Department and **NOT** by embassies/consulates.

So my question is can we apply for a short-stay visa for Finland from the Dutch Embassy here and once we are in Finland apply for a Residency Permit? Is our case exceptional enough? FYI the final interview for the accelerator program was today, so there's no delay on our side, plus also there's no Finnish embassy in our country and applying elsewhere would not only cost us A LOT of money but also time which we don't have any.

I believe our case qualifies as an exceptional case, but I would like to hear your thoughts and if this is really possible?

Also we were in Finland exactly 1 month ago for a similar event for 5 days and another 3 days in France, this visa was issued by the local Dutch Embassy on behalf of Finland. But it was a 10 day single entry visa, so as we know the 90-days-in-180-days rule of EU, will those 10 days also count in the upcoming application?